# SQL SELECT doesn't detect value correctly

Tags: php, mysql

chat.php

```
include_once "config.php";
        $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
        $user_convses_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['user_convses_id']);
        var_dump($_GET, $_GET['user_convses_id']);
        $output = "";
        $sql2 = "SELECT messages.*, apoteker.*, sessionbook.*
                FROM ((sessionbook 
                LEFT JOIN apoteker ON apoteker.unique_id = sessionbook.apt_uniqueid)
                LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.convses_id = sessionbook.convses_id) 
                
                WHERE (convses_id = {$user_convses_id} AND convses_status = 'invalid') AND (outgoing_msg_id = {$outgoing_id} OR incoming_msg_id = {$outgoing_id})
                ORDER BY msg_id";
```

That was my `chat.php` code, everything works fine, except when i add `convses_id = {$user_convses_id}`

$user_convses_id is from `https://domain.tld/test/chat.php?user_convses_id=418845186`

var dump `var_dump($_GET, $_GET['user_convses_id']);`

output  `array(1) { ["user_convses_id"]=> string(9) "418845186" } string(9) "418845186"`

the var dump looks ok for me And i don't have any idea why it doesn't work

Comment: print the $sql2 and analyse the query, if your variable value is coming or not

Comment: _"the var dump looks ok for me"_ - what you are dumping, is not actually what you tried to insert into the query. Your problem is with `$user_convses_id`, so why did you not first and foremost dump _that_?

Comment: @CBroe you're right, value is NULL

Comment: Then `$conn` perhaps did not contain a valid database connection.

Comment: What print `var_dump($user_convses_id);` ? Does your table have record for this id?

Comment: It comes from `https://domain.tld/test/chat.php?user_convses_id=418845186`, i've tried using 2 variable looks like `chat.php?user_convses_id=418845186&another=444444` the `another` works just fine, but the `user_convses_id` showing up but can't be used to `WHERE` the joined table